# Uploading file with other parameters in spring controller

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I am unable to send the multipart file and two text fields from angular post request to spring controller.

My post request is like follows,

```
$scope.data = {
            "file": $scope.uploadFile,
            "doucmentType" : $scope.documentType,
            "otherDocumentType" : $scope.otherDocumentType
    }
```

where $scope.uploadFile is the file object, doucmnetType and otherDocumentType are two text fields that I wish to send to spring controller with the file.

The post request is as follows,

```
$http.post(appPath + '/temp/uploadAttachments',JSON.stringify($scope.data) ).success(function(result) {

    });
```

My spring controller is as follows,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "uploadAttachments", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String uploadAttachments(@RequestBody ReqParam reqParam) {

    JSONObject ret= new JSONObject();
    ret.put("result", true);
    return ret.toString();

}
```

Where ReqParam is pojo class containing the getters and setters of the file with other fields like,

```
private MultipartFile file;

private String doucmentType;

private String otherDocumentType;

public String getOtherDocumentType() {
    return otherDocumentType;
}

public void setOtherDocumentType(String otherDocumentType) {
    this.otherDocumentType = otherDocumentType;
}

public String getDoucmentType() {
    return doucmentType;
}

public void setDoucmentType(String doucmentType) {
    this.doucmentType = doucmentType;
}

public MultipartFile getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(MultipartFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using JSON parse and `@ResponseBody` and your custom model. just use `FormData()` and you need settings `MultipartResolver` in spring.

This is sample code for you :

**Angular**

```
<body ng-app = "myApp">

  <div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
     <input type = "file" file-model = "myFile"/>
     <button ng-click = "uploadFile()">upload me</button>
  </div>

  <script>
     var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

     myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
           restrict: 'A',
           link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
              var modelSetter = model.assign;

              element.bind('change', function(){
                 scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                 });
              });
           }
        };
     }]);

     myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$https:', function ($https:) {
        this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
           var fd = new FormData();
           fd.append('file', file);

           $https:.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
              transformRequest: angular.identity,
              headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
           })

           .success(function(){
           })

           .error(function(){
           });
        }
     }]);

     myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){
        $scope.uploadFile = function(){
           var file = $scope.myFile;

           console.log('file is ' );
           console.dir(file);

           var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
           fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
        };
     }]);

  </script>

</body>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fileUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String uploadFile(MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest req)
        throws SQLException {

    // using file.

    return "success";
}
```